# How to round to 2 decimal 2.2034 and have 2.20 and not 2.2 in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Actually I do not know how this is called and that is why I ask here.

I am working with currency and this way of presentation is important.

In ruby I need to have a value like 2.20 and not 2.2.

**Examples:**

`2.201.round(2)` -> `2.20` and not 2.2

`3.80989.round(2)` -> `3.80` and not 3.8

The problem is with the final 0, when it is another number there is no problem. `2.345.round(2)` -> `2.35`

Any idea?

Comment: are you really working with currency and store data in float???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this using formatting

```
x = 2.2
puts "%.2f" %x # => 2.20
```

When dealing with money and currencies, you shouldn't trust floating point numbers. Why? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201861).

There is [a special gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) for dealing with money.

Comment: Note that the linked question has rounding issues despite using the Money gem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) method:

```
sprintf('%.2f', 2.201)
# => '2.20'
```